# SQL Server: Insert row into table, for all id's not existing yet

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have three tables in MS SQL Server, one with addresses, one with addresstypes and one with assignments of addresstypes:

**Address**:

```
IdAddress   | Name   | ...
1           | xyz
2           | abc    |
...
```

**AddressTypes**

```
IdAddresstype | Caption
1             | Customer
2             | Supplier
...
```

**Address2AddressType**

```
IdAddress2AddressType | IdAddress | IdAddressType
1                     | 1         | 2
3                     | 3         | 2
```

Now I want to insert a row into `Address2AddressType` for each address, which is not assigned yet / not emerging in this table with the Addresstype *Customer*.

So to select those addresses, I use this query:

```sql
SELECT adresses.IdAddress 
FROM [dbo].[Address] AS adresses
WHERE adresses.IdAddress NOT IN (SELECT adresstypeassignment.IdAddress 
                                 FROM [dbo].[Address2AddressType] AS adresstypeassignment)
```

Now I need to find a way to loop through all those results to insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO (Address2AddressType (IdAddress, IdAddresstype)
VALUES (<IdAddress from result>, 1)
```

Can anybody help, please?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Lars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO Address2AddressType (IdAddress, IdAddresstype)
    SELECT a.IdAddress, 1
    FROM [dbo].[Address] a
    WHERE a.IdAddress NOT IN (SELECT ata.IdAddress FROM [dbo].Address2AddressType ata);
```

I also simplified the table aliases.

Note:  I don't recommend `NOT IN` for this purpose, because it does not handle `NULL`s the way you expect (if any values returned by the subquery are `NULL` *no* rows at all will be inserted).  I recommend `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
INSERT INTO Address2AddressType (IdAddress, IdAddresstype)
    SELECT a.IdAddress, 1
    FROM [dbo].[Address] a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM [dbo].Address2AddressType ata
                      WHERE ata.IdAddress = a.IdAddress
                     );
```